# FileSystemView method throwing exception

Tags: java, grails

```
        CHECKDISK = "Local Disk"
        File[] paths
        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView() 
        paths = File.listRoots()
        List<String> drives = new ArrayList<String>()
        for(File path:paths)
        {  
            String drivePath = path.toString().replace('\\', '/'); 
            log.info("get system description : "+fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(path)) 
            if(fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(path).equals(CHECKDISK)){ 
                drives.add(drivePath)
            }
        }
```

When I am executing this code inside the local system, a proper drive list is getting. But after war deployment, It is throwing NullPointerException in log.info() line.
Please guide me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: we need more code... where is log object initialized and how...

Comment: and the full stacktrace!

Comment: 03-07-2017 08:30:10,576 ERROR services.FileService - Error: FileService ---- getDrives ----- null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: ----- null  you are not showing the throw exception line something clearly there someone else has put in that outlines you have a null there